# SQL select using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help to my query, I have this query(see below)

```
select
    empnam as Emp_Name,seccod as DEPT,'' as REMARKS
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN STAT = 'IN' THEN clktim END)[IN]
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN STAT = 'OUT' THEN clktim END) OUT
from
    (select a.clkid,
            case when a.devid = '10' then 'IN' else 'OUT' end as STAT
            , a.clkdat, a.clktim, b.empid, b.empnam, b.seccod,
            row_number() over(partition by clkdat order by dateinsert) as seqnum
     from   ClkInf a
            INNER JOIN EmpInf b ON a.clkid = b.clkid
     where  a.clkdat between (select FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyyMMdd')) 
                         and (select FORMAT(getdate() + 1, 'yyyyMMdd'))
     and    devid in (10, 50)
    ) mak
GROUP BY clkid,clkdat,empnam,seccod
order by DEPT ASC
```

**that resulted to image below**

```
NAME    DEPT IN  OUT
Peter   STP 647  NULL
Jordan  FCW 647  NULL
Mark    EE  724  NULL
Lebron  STP NULL 810
Kobe    STP NULL 813
Chris   TR  729  NULL
Dray    DC  705  NULL
```

if the a chance to get this result?
if ever what query that i need to add/change? thanks

```
NAME    DEPT IN OUT
Peter   STP 647 NULL
Jordan  FCW 647 NULL
Mark    EE  724 NULL
Chris   TR  729 NULL
Dray    DC  705 NULL
```

Comment: are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: @Squirrel sql server

Comment: What logic to achieve your expected output? Why omit those line in result? Because their `IN` value is `NULL`?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach IF(IN!=null || OUT = null) OK
IF(IN=null || OUT != null) will not output
IF(IN!= null || OUT !=null) will not output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `HAVING` clause to check your condition `output: IN not null and OUT is null`:

```
SELECT
    empnam AS Emp_Name,seccod AS DEPT,'' AS REMARKS
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN STAT = 'IN' THEN clktim END)[IN]
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN STAT = 'OUT' THEN clktim END) OUT
FROM
(
    SELECT a.clkid,
            CASE WHEN a.devid = '10' THEN 'IN' ELSE 'OUT' END AS STAT
            , a.clkdat, a.clktim, b.empid, b.empnam, b.seccod,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY clkdat ORDER BY dateinsert) AS seqnum
    FROM   ClkInf a
    INNER JOIN EmpInf b ON a.clkid = b.clkid
    WHERE  a.clkdat BETWEEN (SELECT FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyyMMdd')) 
                         AND (SELECT FORMAT(getdate() + 1, 'yyyyMMdd'))
        AND    devid IN (10, 50)
) mak
GROUP BY clkid, clkdat, empnam, seccod
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN STAT = 'IN' THEN clktim END) IS NOT NULL
    AND MAX(CASE WHEN STAT = 'OUT' THEN clktim END) IS NULL
ORDER BY DEPT ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add one more extra FILTER condition:

```
select * from (
    select
        empnam as Emp_Name,seccod as DEPT,'' as REMARKS
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN STAT = 'IN' THEN clktim END) in_
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN STAT = 'OUT' THEN clktim END) OUT
    from
        (select a.clkid,
                case when a.devid = '10' then 'IN' else 'OUT' end as STAT
                , a.clkdat, a.clktim, b.empid, b.empnam, b.seccod,
                row_number() over(partition by clkdat order by dateinsert) as seqnum
         from   ClkInf a
                INNER JOIN EmpInf b ON a.clkid = b.clkid
         where  a.clkdat between (select FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyyMMdd')) 
                             and (select FORMAT(getdate() + 1, 'yyyyMMdd'))
         and    devid in (10, 50)
        ) mak
    GROUP BY clkid,clkdat,empnam,seccod
    order by DEPT ASC
) k
where in_ is not null;
```

Comment: Really? You couldn't think of a better nick than KKK?